# My sql query doesn't insert any data into database table when I use the variables corresponding to the input boxes

Tags: javascript, html, next.js

I am using phpmyadmin to store dummy data. Currently trying to insert data from a form. But it doesn't insert anything if I use the variables in the sql query. I couldn't figure out how to do this. And I'm very new to coding so correct me if I am wrong. I have also tried learning routes to no avail. I couldn't understand how it is done.

This is just a degree level project, simple web based app. Therefore, I'm running client side queries, if that matters.

This is the add member page where I just have a form and a function that runs when I click submit button that has the sql query.

```
import { sql_query } from '../../../lib/db';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Link from 'next/link'



export const AddForm = () => {
    const [fullname, setFullname] = useState('')
    const [id, setId] = useState('')
    console.log(id)
    function AddMember() {
        try {
            sql_query(
                `INSERT INTO members (id, Fullname) VALUES ( '${id}', '${fullname}' )`
            );
        } catch (error) {
            throw Error(error.message)
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className=" border h-20">
                <h1 className="p-5 font-bold text-red-500">Adding Member</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="fixed top-0 left-0 w-screen h-screen flex items-center justify-center ">
                <div className="flex flex-col items-end">
                    <Link href={"/members"}>
                        <button className="bg-white rounded-full w-10 h-10 text-center p-2 m-2 left-0 hover:rotate-180 origin-center transition-all">X</button>
                    </Link>
                    <form method="POST" className="bg-white shadow-md rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4">
                        <div className="flex mb-2">
                            <div className="pr-5">
                                <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="id">ID </label>
                                <input className="shadow appearance-none border rounded py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none" onChange={e => setId(e.target.value)} id="id" name='id' type="number" placeholder="ID Card Number"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="pr-5">
                                <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="fullname">Fullname</label>
                                <input className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-96 py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" onChange={e => setFullname(e.target.value)} id="fullname" name='fullname' type="text" placeholder="Fullname"></input>
                            </div>
                        <br></br>
                        <button onClick={AddMember()} type="submit" className="bg-red-500 rounded-full p-2 text-white hover:bg-red-400">Add Member</button>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>

        </>
    )

}



export default AddForm;
```

This is the file in which connection to the database is made.

```
import mysql from 'serverless-mysql'

export const db = mysql({
    config: {
        host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
        database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
        user: process.env.MYSQL_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,

    }
})

export async function sql_query(query_string, values = []) {
    try {
        const results = await db.query(query_string, values)
        await db.end()
        return results
    } catch (error) {
    }
}
```

Comment: if you replace ${id} and ${username} with hard coded value does it work ?

Comment: @Emilien Yes. It does.

Comment: Ok, so the good thing is that the sql_query method works. Does it insert when you click on the button or when the page is loaded?

Comment: can you also add a ```console.log(fullname)``` at the start of you addMember function to check whether it's properly called when you click on it and if it has the right data?

Comment: How do I check if it inserts when I click on the button or when the page is loaded? And also, it does log the value I type into the textboxes.

Comment: I have updated the post. Please see if it is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is here:

```
<button onClick={AddMember()} type="submit" className="bg-red-500 rounded-full p-2 text-white hover:bg-red-400">Add Member</button>
```

You are trying to call the function AddMember but when Coding with next.js you need to remove the round brackets to call a function with onClick!

So correct would be:

```
<button onClick={AddMember} type="submit" className="bg-red-500 rounded-full p-2 text-white hover:bg-red-400">Add Member</button>
```

Now, the function should be called on button click and the sql query should be executed as intended

The corresponding entry in the next.js documentation can be found [here](https://nextjs.org/learn/foundations/from-javascript-to-react/adding-interactivity-with-state)

Comment: I've seen this suggestion somewhere else but it doesn't work. When I remove the brackets, and execute the code with hard coded values instead of ${id} and ${fullname}, it does not insert anything. But with the brackets, it does.

Comment: Interesting! Also as you access a database you should use an async function with the await keyword infornt of the sql_query()

Comment: I see. After I make it an async function and add await keyword, it throws the error about the brackets. 

Warning: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type.

So I have removed the parenthesis.

Comment: I have updated the post. Please see if it is relevant.

Comment: Can anyone help. Just stuck at this point now.